# Can't compile iOS-App in Ad-Hoc mode (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So basically I'm following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/#Before_you_Submit) official Xamarin guide to release my app in the AppStore.

However no matter what I try (changing signing profiles, different build options) the solution-process crashes every time after 1-2 minutes with different errors that don't explain what exactly went wrong (signing error, user aborted?!, etc.).

After the error is shown I always have to reconnect to the Mac.
What could be the problem?

EDIT:

> Tool exited with code: 1. Output: CSSM_SignData returned: 800108E6
>   /Users/metadokentwicklung/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/mWIDAS_iOS/806c20450998d745a5c8df0e4928100f/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mWIDAS_iOS.app:
>   errSecInternalComponent   mWIDAS_iOS

I tried the publish profiles (Ad-Hoc,AppStore,automatic) and provisioning profile.

Comment: try rebooting the Mac

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay solved the problem myself a few days ago. Dumb mistake on my behlaf.

I use the same monitor for the Mac Mini and the Windows PC so I didn't see the popup on the Mac prompting me to accept the use of the keyfile.

After I agreed to it everything worked like a charm.

Comment: You saved my day with this answer... switched the monitor and saw a little window with a password-input... wow... thats just dumb. Thanks

Comment: Had the same issue, very annoying... so Jenkins build fails, remote ssh build command fails, going locally on the mac and running the msbuild command there manually ... succeeds.
Basically whenever you change your signing certs or keys in the keychain and then try to build from Visual Studio or Jenkins always keep an eye on the Mac, because it is going to display a popup and prompt you for a password, for Visual Studio or Jenkins trying to access new key in the keychain. Type the password and tick Always Allow ! @fbueckle Lost few hours on this as I was using the same monitor for both too...

Comment: That was so dumm of me too. I just generated the first .ipa file, following all the required things to do. But then, i completely forgot to go to the Mac-agent to give the passord and i kept getting this Dame failure message. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by:

1. Cleaning my solution
2. Closing VS4Mac
3. Shut down Macbook Pro
4. Start Macbook Pro
5. Reopen my solution
6. Build iOS head project (I am working in Xamarin.Forms)

And it built successfully this time.  I am noticing lots of issues from Windows VS are creeping into VS4Mac by each update.  Not sure why this was happening but that resolved my issue